# How to change recovery mode keys Volumeup+power to some other key options

Tags: android

Working on android recovery mode. pressing volume up & power button will open Android recovery mode . the hardware i am using , that does not have any volume button. I want to define new key options to enter into recovery mode. how can i change the options from Volumeup+power to some other option ?

Comment: which device you have ???

Comment: Off-topic question...this has nothing to do with programming! This is just a question about changing your settings...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. That piece of information is handled by the hardware manufacturers and you won't have access to it. You can instead use `adb` to go to recovery mode by using the following command.

```
adb reboot recovery
```